# Using SSH2 and URLrewrite and get stackoverflow error

Tags: java, stack-overflow, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using urlrewritefilter 4.0.3, I always got stackoverflow error. Here is my config:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>statusEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/annotation/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is my url rewrite pattern:

```xml
<rule>
    <note>
        Redirect find annotation by object id.
    </note>
    <from>/annotation/([a-z0-9]+)</from>
    <to type="forward">/annotation/getAnnotationByObjectID.action?oid=$1</to>
</rule>
```

Once I run it I always got :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
...
root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:403)
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:403)
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:403)
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:403)
```

I am mad about it. Please if you know how it is, help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regular expression in the `<from>` rule is not anchored. Apparently, the rules are looking for any match inside the URL, so if they are not anchored (have a `^` at the beginning and a `$` at the end), they will match anything inside the URL.

As a result, your target URL `/annotation/getAnnotationByObjectID.action?oid=$1` actually matches your `from` rule (The part `/annotation/get` does). So it runs the same rule over and over again in an endless loop.

The solution should be to anchor the rule:

```xml
<from>^/annotation/([a-z0-9]+)$</from>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works. For some reason, I tried this way, but it didn't work. And the example in urlrewrite.xml kind of miss leading. It doesn't have ^ and $ in the example of regex.

Comment: The most trustworthy place is the [manual](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/4.0/). The example is probably just there to show you syntax, not actual use.

Answer (score 1):

The regex is not matched against the URL, it tries to find the pattern instead. See https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/issues/detail?id=20

```
public class RewriteSanityCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String from = "/annotation/([a-z0-9]+)";
        String to = "/annotation/getAnnotationByObjectID.action?oid=$1";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(from);

        if (pattern.matcher(to).find()) {
            System.out.println("Infinite loop");
        } else {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
    }

}
```